# How to delete an entire group of artifacts from Nexus?

Tags: nexus, delete-file

I want to delete the entire version of a project from the Nexus Repository Manager. I have tried executing the following command without success:

```
curl --request DELETE --user "user:password" 
https://nexus.website.lk/repository/snapshots/com/ksiot/edge_node_windows_service_v2/edge_node_windows_service_v2/1.0.10-SNAPSHOT`
```

When I specify an artifact in the project it works fine:

```
curl --request DELETE --user "user:password" 
https://nexus.website.lk/repository/snapshots/com/ksiot/edge_node_windows_service_v2/edge_node_windows_service_v2/1.0.10-SNAPSHOT/prometheus_libs-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a following slash (it failed without slash for a similar use-case, and worked with it).

```
curl --request DELETE --user "user:password" 
https://nexus.website.lk/repository/snapshots/com/ksiot/edge_node_windows_service_v2/edge_node_windows_service_v2/1.0.10-SNAPSHOT/
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Nexus 2.x, you can just delete the folder from the `/storage` and then reindex.

As a note: Please make sure that deleting a version from Nexus is the absolute exception - usually, release versions should stay "forever" to ensure build reproducibility.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this answer is received so badly? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Perhaps it's because the OP tried to delete a `-SNAPSHOT` anyway, which makes your, otherwise absolutely correct, "release versions" note a bit misplaced. Anyway, at least one downvote is cancelled out now. :)

Comment: @Fabian, I would say the answer is very 'raw' as it implies messing with nexus internals, which one has to be familiar with. As a developer I wouldn't feel comfortable going this deep to delete anything. Just a thought, not sure the downvotes are deserved.